# rails are functions defined in tests available in controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

could someone explain the following method/function and explain if it is located in test/test_helper.rb how other non test classes/controllers  get access to it?

```
# Logs in a test user.
  def log_in_as(user, options = {})
    password = options[:password] || 'password'
    remember_me = options[:remember_me] || '1'
    if integration_test?
      post login_path, session: { email: user.email,
                                  password: password,
                                  remember_me: remember_me }
    else
      session[:user_id] = user.id
    end
  end
```

Comment: The method is to simulate a login for an integration test.  Why would you want to call it from non-test controllers or classes?

Comment: this comes from RailsTutorial by Hartl.  I got the integration test but he has an else clause and the log_in_as is called from a controller.  That confuses me as I thought the tests where just for the tests

Comment: This is about page 460 of the tutorial right?  He never calls it from a controller, he only calls it from tests.

Comment: The if / else / end is to determine if it's an integration_test or some other test, but it's always a test.

Comment: thanks.  do you know of a good tutorial on tests?

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html is a good resource.  The Hartl tutorial covers it well.  There's a good book called "Agile Web Development with Rails" that takes a very Test Driven Development approach.

Comment: thanks again.  So, tests rely on information from the controllers and helpers that are not tests but those controllers (that are not tests) don't get any information from the tests.  It makes sense but so much is going on.  It hard to wrap my head around all of this.

Comment: Well, tests are *testing* the operation of the system so they test the controllers, the views, and (in the case of integration tests) the whole business flow.  Test helpers provide some methods that the tests can use (like simulating a user login).  Tests will call controller methods, but that's to make sure the controllers are working as desired.